# Not clickable transparent window on ubuntu desktop

Tags: screen, window, transparency

The past couple of days two transparent window areas appeared on my ubuntu desktop, which are not clickable.

This is a printscreen on my desktop where you can clearly see the windows I am referring to.
[image]

Do you have any idea what has caused them and how I can remove them? I tried closing all open applications and rebooting and they didn't seem to disappear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open a terminal.

Run `xprop`.

Click on the window. In your terminal, all information will appear.

Comment: Thank you!! It was a window by nautilus so I ended the process and it disappeared! Cheers!

Comment: Worked great! ran `ps -ef` and found the `pid` that matched the `_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = ####` line. The CMD column in the `ps` output points towards the binary causing the problem. My issue was some kind of [drag and drop utility from vmware tools failing](https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools/issues/445).